# What component is causing the monitor to go to sleep?

Tags: monitor, screensaver, kiosk

We make systems based on Ubuntu 14.04 which we configure to kiosk mode, meaning we change the session to run our application and never present any desktop. Our session file is:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Kiosk Mode
Comment=Product Kiosk Mode
Exec=/usr/share/xsessions/Kiosk.sh
Type=Application
```

And the Kisok.sh script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Undefining the QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME environment variable disables the appmenu-qt5 package. That package is for putting
# the app menu up in the global bar rather than on the app. It has a bug and results in no menu anywhere. We want the
# menu on the app anyway.
export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=

metacity --replace &

# This sets the window decoration theme to our theme, which removes the title bar on maximized windows - hence on
# the main window.
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme Product

while true; do
    ~/Product.sh --kioskMode
    result=$?
    if [ $result -eq 125 ]; then
      poweroff
    fi
    .... test result for other exit conditions ...
    sleep 3s 
done
```

As you can see, we replace the window manager with `metacity`, I'm not sure if that's relevant or not.

Our application controls the gnome-screensaver to prevent screen blanking under various circumstance. However, some other component in the system is shutting down the monitor output after 10 minutes.

I have removed the `gnome-screensaver`, `gnome-power-manager` and `upower` packages and the problem still occurs.

I have checked various logs and can't find and events relating to monitor blanking/power down that might indicate what c
omponent is causing this.

What other components might be involved in powering down the monitor?

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer. Based on these two questions

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2104802

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2098422

I created an /etc/X11/xorg.conf file like this:

```
Section "ServerFlags"
Option "blanktime" "0"
Option "standbytime" "0"
Option "suspendtime" "0"
Option "offtime" "0"
EndSection
```

That stopped the undesired power down of the monitor.